# How to display Model internal validation messages in asp.net mvc 2?

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I have developed the application in asp.net mvc 2 with c# language. I have deployed it successfully on IIS 5.1 ,  working perfect. but one of form only displaying the red shade box after  execution. It seems like this : [image]

May be this is issue of date format but tough I give it as dd/MM/yyyy it shows same. Also While I have debug the application it is showing the Model.IsValid = false. I just wnt to know what should be the issue there ? Why it is not showing any message on the page ?

Comment: Problem Solved by adding       <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfRegistration)%> under the field in view